# How do I write my own exception handling for Crawler4J?

Tags: java, exception, web-crawler, crawler4j

I want my crawler to wait for 5 minutes if it gets a SocketConnectException(i.e. if the internet connection is down) and resume again and also maybe send a mail to an admin about this.
I have seen the source code, and the methods that throw this exception are private, so I cannot overload them. Is there any other option to handle this exception other than changing the source code? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because the only thing I can think of at this point is to catch the exception somewhere higher, and trigger another crawler from the last url of killed crawler, which I think this may lead back to pages  you already visited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can now be achieved.

One of the recent (from the end of July 2015) commits fixed it.

Please override:
[onUnhandledException(.. Throwable ex)](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/crawler/WebCrawler.java#L221)

On that overriden method you can compare the class of ex to SocketConnect...Exception and do whatever you want there.